# C++ compile error constructing object with rvalue std::string

Tags: c++, constructor, std, stdstring, most-vexing-parse

I'm faced with a compile error that I don't even know how to describe! It completely baffles me.

**The situation**:

Code tries to create an object on the stack with an rvalue std::string that is initialized with a char*.

**The code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(double d)
            : mD(d)
        {
        }

        Foo(const std::string& str)
        {
            try
            {
                mD = std::stod(str);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        Foo(const Foo& other)
            : mD(other.mD)
        {
        }

        virtual ~Foo() {}

    protected:
        double mD;
};

class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
            : mA(a)
            , mB(b)
        {
        }

        virtual ~Bar() {}

    protected:
        Foo mA;
        Foo mB;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) { return 0; }

    Foo a(std::string(argv[1]));
    Foo b(std::string(argv[2]));

    Bar wtf(a, b);
}
```

**The compiler error**:

```
>g++ -std=c++11 wtf.cpp
wtf.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
wtf.cpp:58:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Bar::Bar(Foo (&)(std::string*), Foo (&)(std::string*))’
     Bar wtf(a, b);
                 ^
wtf.cpp:38:9: note: candidate: Bar::Bar(const Foo&, const Foo&)
         Bar(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
         ^
wtf.cpp:38:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo(std::string*) {aka Foo(std::basic_string<char>*)}’ to ‘const Foo&’
wtf.cpp:35:7: note: candidate: Bar::Bar(const Bar&)
 class Bar
       ^
wtf.cpp:35:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
>
```

You won't believe what the/a workaround is, either (or at least *I* don't). If I call substr(0) on my rvalue std::string, the compiler is pacified. But I don't see why this would make a difference. After all...

```
std::string(argv[1]).substr(0)
```

...is itself still an rvalue. I don't see why it's different from the compiler's point of view.

I.e. the following change to main(...) allows compilation success:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) { return 0; }

    Foo a(std::string(argv[1]).substr(0));
    Foo b(std::string(argv[2]).substr(0));

    Bar wtf(a, b);
}
```

Couple of additional data points:

- Compiling without C++11 makes no difference (I only include it to get access to std::stod(...), which is besides the point).
- g++ (GCC) 5.4.0.
- Compilation environment is cygwin.
- I have tried modifying Bar's constructor to take std::string (instead of std::string&) - it does not affect the compile error.

I'm **dying** to know what this problem is. This feels so out of left field.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Taking `std::string&` for `Foo`'s constructor in this case would be patently wrong - it would be taking a reference to a temporary object, which is problematic at best (though I can't remember if it's illegal or just undefined).

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Just fyi, it is legal because I'm using a const ref. Different than a non-const ref. See the answers RE: most vexing parse; it's fascinating!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that try-catch for the `stod` call, if all you are doing is rethrowing the exception then there's no need for a try-catch.

Comment: @StoneThrow Ah right, missed the `const`. And yes, the answers are fascinating. I had no idea this was a thing!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg True enough. Point taken; thank you.

Comment: `clang++` gives better error messages.

Comment: I don't think that explicit mention of `std::string` is required, as `argv[1]` alone should resolve to trigger the `char *` constructor. Brace/Uniform initialisation might still be needed, though, and is syntactically superior for all situations (...unless it causes ambiguity with an constructor taking `std::initializer_list`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a less common example of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The declaration

```
Foo a(std::string(argv[1]));
```

is not calling the constructor of `Foo` with a string argument; instead, it is declaring `a` to be a function taking an array of 1 `std::string` (adjusted to a pointer to `std::string`) and returning `Foo`. That's why the error message is mentioning a `Foo (&)(std::string*)` type: that's the type the compiler thinks `a` and `b` are. (The `(&)` in the message just means that it's an lvalue.)

Adding `.substr(0)` disambiguates the declaration so that it cannot be parsed as a function declaration.

Brace initialization is a more elegant way to solve the problem:

```
Foo a{std::string(argv[1])};
```

Comment: This right here is why I always default to brace initialization when possible.

Comment: This is fascinating; thank you. I guess I'm a bit unclear why the compiler needs to consider this possibly a function definition since it's within the scope of another function (i.e. main(...)). For that matter, also why there would be an implicit adjustment to a pointer to std::string. I'm going to try to wean myself onto brace initialization, though. Thank you again. This was vexing, indeed!

Comment: @StoneThrow function declarations may appear inside functions . (A poor language feature IMO, but one that can't be removed for historical compatibility)

Comment: @StoneThrow The compiler is not considering it a function *definition* (that would indeed be illegal). It is considering it a function *declaration,* though, which can appear in other functions just fine.

Comment: @StoneThrow: "implicit adjustment".  Function cannot take arrays as arguments (although C++ functions can take *references* to arrays).  As a convenience to the user, both C and C++ allow you to declare a function as taking an array, but the argument is *implicitly adjusted* to actually be a pointer.  So `void foo(int a[1])` becomes `void foo(int *a)`.

Comment: @MartinBonner: inconvenience* ;)

Comment: Great answer - one niggle, though: "less common" compared to what exactly? This is textbook MVP. You're not considering the common mistake `Foo a()` to be the most vexing parse, are you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the usual examples don't contain an array.

Comment: @Brian: Okay, yep, that's an added dimension :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, it was clearly a mistake in retrospect, but it's about 30 years too late to change it now.

Answer (score 10):

If you look closer at the error message you will see that you are trying to construct the `Bar` object `wtf` with two *functions*. What's happening here is vexing, so vexing it's been officially named [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

What's happening is that you declare `a` and `b` as *functions*. Functions that take a pointer to `std::string` as argument and return a `Foo` object.

If you have a C++11 capable compiler you can use curly-braces instead of parentheses when constructing the `Foo` objects:

```
Foo a{std::string(argv[1])};
Foo b{std::string(argv[2])};
```

If you had an older compiler you can use copy-initialization instead:

```
Foo a = Foo(std::string(argv[1]));
Foo b = Foo(std::string(argv[2]));
```

It should also work fine if you *don't* explicitly create `std::string` objects for the constructor argument, and let the compiler handle that:

```
Foo a(argv[1]);
Foo b(argv[2]);
```

Comment: In case you're still active on this thread: I'm not sure I understand yet why a (and b) could be interpreted as functions that take *pointers* to `std::string`. What you say is borne out by the compiler error, but how could the compiler justify an implicit conversion from an object to a pointer? The "most vexing parse" link didn't quite answer this per my reading.

Comment: @StoneThrow Declaring a function to take an array by value (such as `int foo(int x[3])` is just alternate syntax for taking a pointer (`int foo(int *x)`). This has always been the case in both C and C++. IOW, the compiler thinks your function has a parameter named `argv` which is a 1-sized array of `std::string`. For a function parameter, that's the same as a pointer to `std::string`.

Comment: @Agnew I still don't get where the array comes from, since there is no `std::string[]` in the argument to purported-function `a`; there is `std::string(something[])` which seems quite different to me due to the extra parentheses and extra identifier. It seems to make more sense (hah!) that `a` would be seen as taking a function named `std::string` which takes an array/pointer as argument. But that doesn't fit with what clang (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)) makes of it: `Foo (std::string (*))`, whatever /that/ is again.

Comment: @OlafSeibert `argv[1]` (for example) is a pointer to `char`, i.e. `char*`. So the compiler sees `std::string(char*)` and due to the syntactic rules of the language in the context (you really have to read [the specification](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) for the details) thinks it is equal to `std::string*`. There's really not much more to say. If you want the details [read the specification](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf). Read the actually error message. And trust us that this is what is happening. :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems compiler takes the part

```
Foo a(std::string(argv[1]));
Foo b(std::string(argv[2]));
```

as function declaretions. Try this instead:

```
Foo a = std::string(argv[1]);
Foo b = std::string(argv[2]);
```

or to clarify that constructor should be called:

```
Foo a = Foo(std::string("1"));
Foo b = Foo(std::string("2"));
```

Comment: ...or just use uniform initialisation, since bypassing things like the most vexing parse is one of its main rationales/successes! **`Foo a{std::string(argv[1])}`**.