# (Why) Is this an example of a vexing parse?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

Is this an example of a vexing parse in C++?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class ScopeLock
{
public:
  ScopeLock(pthread_mutex_t& m)
    : mrMutex(m)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mrMutex);
  }

  ~ScopeLock()
  {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mrMutex);
  }

protected:
  pthread_mutex_t& mrMutex;
};

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    pthread_mutex_init(&m_, NULL);
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_);
  }

  void Func()
  {
    ScopeLock(m_); // Is this a vexing parse?
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  pthread_mutex_t m_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.Func();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp: In member function \u2018void Foo::Func():
main.cpp:37:17: error: no matching function for call to 'ScopeLock::ScopeLock()'
     ScopeLock(m_);
                 ^
main.cpp:37:17: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:7:3: note: ScopeLock::ScopeLock(pthread_mutex_t&)
   ScopeLock(pthread_mutex_t& m)
   ^
main.cpp:7:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:4:7: note: ScopeLock::ScopeLock(const ScopeLock&)
 class ScopeLock
       ^
main.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I think the compiler fails because it is trying to create a `ScopeLock` object (named m_) with no ctor arguments, and correctly identifies that the only `ScopeLock` ctor takes one `pthread_mutex_t&` as argument -- is that correct?

Why is this a vexing parse, though (if it is)? Why is line 37 not interpreted as creation of an anonymous `ScopeLock` object with ctor argument `m_`?

If the above is an example of a vexing parse, why is the below not a vexing parse?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    pStr = "Foo";
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
  }

  void Func()
  {
    const std::string& rStr = std::string(pStr);
    std::cout << rStr << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  const char* pStr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.Func();

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and output:

```
>g++ main.cpp
>./a.out
Foo
>
```

The second code block seems very analogous to the first. Why, then does the compiler not treat line 18 as creation of a `std::string` named `pStr` with no ctor arguments? The `cout` of `rStr` resulting in "Foo" actually shows that an anonymous `std::string` was created with `const char*` argument.

I'd be grateful if anyone could shed light here. Thank you.

**Update**
I just noticed that in the first code block changing this:

```
ScopeLock(m_); // Is this a vexing parse?
```

to this:

```
const ScopeLock& rSl = ScopeLock(m_); // Is this a vexing parse?
```

results in compilation passing. So something about turning the anonymous object to an rvalue fixes the vexing parse problem? I'm unclear.

On the flip side, in the second code block, changing this:

```
const std::string& rStr = std::string(pStr);
```

to this:

```
std::string(pStr);
```

compiles just fine. However the resulting `cout` of `pStr` is empty. I think this confirms that the compiler is actually creating a `std::string` named `pStr` using the default constructor. So actually that is analogous to what it was trying to do in the first code block.

I'd still be grateful if someone could confirm if what I've surmised is correct.

Comment: Note that even if `ScopeLock(m_);` were interpreted as creating a temporary object, it's almost certainly useless in real code.  The temporary object's lifetime would end at the end of the statement, so all you would be doing would be locking the mutex and then immediately unlocking it.

Comment: The rule is that if an entire *statement* can be parsed as either a declaration or an expression, it is parsed as a declaration. So if you use `ScopeLock(m_)` in the initializer of a declaration, it obviously can't be a declaration in and of itself, so it is interpreted as an expression.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's an interesting point: is it not the case that the temporary object's lifespan is the enclosing parentheses? That would've been true for a named objects, but not so for anonymous objects?

Comment: Correct, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime would be good reading for that.  Particularly the point: "All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created..." where here the full-expression would be `ScopeLock(m_)`, or in C++11 `ScopeLock{m_}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "canonical" meaning of the "[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)" refers to the ambiguity between object declaration and function declaration.

What you have in your case is a different ambiguity: an ambiguity between object declaration and functional-style cast (more formally: functional notation of explicit type conversion, see 5.2.3). This latter ambiguity is resolved in favor of object declaration. Hence the error. Your code is seen by the compiler as a simple

```
ScopeLock m_;
```

which makes it to complain about missing default constructor.

> **6.8 Ambiguity resolution [stmt.ambig]**
>
> **1** There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression statement with a function-style explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration.

Whether you want to call it another flavor of "most vexing parse" is up to you.

There are many different ways to make the compiler to interpret it as an expression instead of declaration. You can also do it as

```
0, ScopeLock(m_);
```

or as

```
(ScopeLock(m_));
```

Comment: From this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989211/c-compile-error-constructing-object-with-rvalue-stdstring I learned the compiler discards parentheses under some of these ambiguous parse conditions - I'm not 100% certain on the rules, but it looks like this is another example of that, I guess.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "functional-style cast". What does the compiler see as casting going on here?

Comment: @StoneThrow: Um... Every time you use `Type(parameters)` syntax you are formally using a functional-style cast (or more formally "explicit type conversion in functional notation", if you prefer). Explicit construction of temporary objects, e.g. `std::string("Hello")` is syntactically a functional notation of explicit type conversion: `"Hello"` is explicitly converted to `std::string` type. And explicit type conversion is exactly what you tried to do with your `ScopeLock(m_)`. That's what it is called at the grammatical level.

Comment: I learned several new things from this post. Thanks for educating me on this.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is line 37 not interpreted as creation of an anonymous `ScopeLock` object with ctor argument `m_`?

It's because the Standard has a rule that if code has structure that can be interpreted as either a declaration or a function call, treatment as the declaration is chosen.

It doesn't worry about whether treatment as a declaration causes an error later.

If you think about it, having a fallback to an entirely different interpretation would cause some very nasty action-at-a-distance results during code maintenance.  Imagine if you wrote this code and it was accepted as a function-style-cast, and later someone added a default constructor...

Comment: I don't see why there's ambiguity between a declaration or a function. Aren't both possibilities declarations? One option is declaring an anonymous `ScopeLock` with ctor argument `pStr` and the other is declaring a `ScopeLock` named `pStr` with no ctor arguments. What am I missing in how I interpret this?

Comment: The ambiguity in this case is completely different: there's no possibility of interpreting this as function call.

Comment: @StoneThrow: There's no such thing as a declaration of an anonymous object, a declaration with no declarator-id is no declaration at all.  It would have been an expression whose value was a temporary instance of type `ScopeLock`, created by a functional-style cast a/k/a "explicit constructor call".  Note that the sentence in your question said "creation of an anonymous object", which isn't incorrect.  A cast does create an object; it does not declare one.

Comment: @AnT: A function-style cast is so named because it matches the syntax of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace
`ScopeLock(m_);` to `ScopeLock s(m_);`. The object needed its name.

-

Maybe compiler was seeing `ScopeLock(m_)` as `ScopeLock m_`. I compiled with clang, and it showed similar error message.

Following line compiles without any complaint :

```
void Func()
{
  ScopeLock(m)(m_);
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't actually answer the question.